# Firing order of cached events

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

Say I have a simple form with only two text boxes and a button.  The text boxes have `AutoPostBack` set to false.  Say put some code inside of the `TextChanged` event of those to write to the response stream saying which TextChanged event was fired after a button is clicked and the form is submitted to the web server.  Is there a way to control the firing order of cached events?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace IsPostBack___Part_8
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Text box 1 event fire");
        }

        protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Text box 2 event fired");
        }
        //dummy button click handler here
    }
}
```

With that code and nothing else on the form it doesn't matter which text box is changed first, they fire in the same order.  Is the firing order of cached events determined by its place in the html?

Comment: you should add the correct tag to say if it's asp.net or what ever

Comment: that's an interesting `namespace` name you have chosen..

Comment: @DJKRAZE I typed the name of the project as `text - more text`, but the spaces and dashes are converted to underscores :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft you should not rely on a specific order of events. But in general events will fire in order of controls location within page markup.

So if your layout is

```
[TextBox1]

[TextBox2]

[Button1]
```

Event's will fire in order:

```
Page_Load

TextBox1_Changed

TextBox2_Changed

Button1_Click
```

You may try to change the order of events by rearranging controls on the page.

Comment: that's kind of what I thought, but I thought it would be neat if you could access a sequence of cached events with an array index or something similar.